# How to get the sequence number of $Revisions field?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

Actually I have to take the sequence number in $Revisions field.

[image: Please see the image below., I need to get the marked value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, @Elements($Revisions)

Comment: Does that still work if your number of revisions exceeds the number actually? We have a database in which some documents have over 100 revisions and not every date displays when looking at properties, so I assume not all are stored.

Comment: There is a high default limit for entries in $Revisions, but it can be lowered.  See here http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/limit-size-of-updatedby-and-revisions-fields

Comment: So, @Elements($Revisions) only works if the number of revisions does not exceed the limit. Raising the limit results in more data being saved -- one of our applications has many documents with over 140 revisions since the "refresh all documents" in a particular view once a week (which I know is just ridiculous, btw). We keep only 8, so disk space is not compromised....

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way to get this information is with the NSFItemQueryEx call in the Notes C API.